# Old anime with a blue robot that was found by a boy. That robot lost his memory

Tags: story-identification, anime

Looking for an old anime with a blue robot that was found by a boy. That robot lost his memory. The face of the robot was on a display. I don't remember very well; they were fighting together, and that blue robot was very powerful. If I am not wrong, I can remember also a scene where there was a fight scene near two sky towers.

This isn't *FLCL* (*Fooly Cooly*) where [Canti](https://flcl.fandom.com/wiki/Canti) would have been the robot. The robot looks very similar to the robot from the movie, real steel.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)